# grep - regex to include/exclude similar pattern in loop

Tags: regex, grep

I have 2 similar pattern (`skylab/plat-kk & skylab/plat-kk-manager`) and grep'ing the log file and counting the occurrence of line containing pattern

```
skylab/plat-kk-manager-12345
skylab/plat-kk-12345
```

I my project i am storing all the patterns in property file like

```
skylab/plat-kk 
skylab/plat-kk-manager
actual=$(grep -io "${patterb_arr[j]}" ${stack_file}
```

1. When `${patterb_arr[j]} = skylab/plat-kk` , it returns line containing a) `skylab/plat-kk-manager-12345 & b)skylab/plat-kk-12345` ( where as i want only `skylab/plat-kk-12345`)
2. when `${patterb_arr[j]}=skylab/plat-kk-manager` , it returns line containing  `skylab/plat-kk-manager-12345` , that is expected.

how to I make the regex generic so that it dosent affect when in loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your regex more specific. In this case, for instance you could grep `"${patterb_arr[j]}-[0-9]\{5\}"`.